# parse rss feed using javascript

Tags: javascript, rss

I am parsing an RSS feed using PHP and JavaScript. First I created a proxy with PHP to obtain the RSS feed. Then get individual data from this RSS feed using JavaScript. My issue with with the JavaScript. I am able to get the entire JavaScript document if I use `console.log(rssData);` with no errors. If I try to get individual elements within this document say for example: `<title>`, `<description>`, or `<pubDate>` using `rssData.getElementsByName("title");` it gives an error "Uncaught TypeError: Object....has no method 'getElementsByName'". So my question is how to I obtain the elements in the RSS feed?

**Javascript (Updated)**

```
function httpGet(theUrl) {
    var xmlHttp = null;

    xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHttp.open("GET", theUrl, false);
    xmlHttp.send(null);
    return xmlHttp.responseXML;
}

// rss source
var rssData = httpGet('http://website.com/rss.php');

// rss values
var allTitles = rssData.getElementsByTagName("title");    // title
var allDate = rssData.getElementsByTagName("pubDate");    // date
```

Comment: `xmlHttp.responseText` is a `String`. `String`s do not have a `getElementsByName()` function. Are you expecting an XML response? Try `xmlHttp.responseXML` instead. Also, you might run into cross-domain issues doing this with JS. You might want to get the feed on the PHP side through an AJAX request to your own application.

Comment: @Cory thank you for the response, and yes `xmlHttp.responseXML` is exactly what I was looking for. I also added the origin policy header to all access.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing the last line of the `httpGet` function to:

```
return xmlHttp.responseXML;
```

After all, you are expecting an XML response back. You may also need to add this line to your PHP proxy:

```
header("Content-type: text/xml");
```

To force the return content to be sent as XML.

Comment: `return xmlHttp.responseXML;` is exactly what I needed thank you.

Comment: Can you help me with one more thing? I want to loop over all the dates and only return the titles that match the current date of today. I updated my post.

Comment: That is another question entirely.